# Filebeat: Monitor two levels of directory hierarchy

Tags: logging, filebeat

## My problem

Consider the following directory structure:

```
/var/log/quodo/campaigns/deployment_29/campaign-32/users.log
/var/log/quodo/campaigns/deployment_29/campaign-12/ads.log
/var/log/quodo/campaigns/deployment_55/campaign-77/users.log
/var/log/quodo/campaigns/deployment_55/campaign-37/ads.log
...
```

I would like to log-ship all the logs under `/var/log/quodo/campaigns/<whatever1>/<whatever2>` to ElasticSearch using Filebeat.

Filebeat [does not feature recursive monitoring of a directory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration.html):

> To fetch all files from a predefined level of subdirectories, the following pattern can be used: `/var/log/*/*.log`.
>
> This fetches all `.log` files from the subfolders of `/var/log`. It does not fetch log files from the `/var/log` folder itself. **Currently it is not possible to recursively fetch all files in all subdirectories of a directory.**

## What have I tried

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/quodo/campaigns/*/*/*
  scan_frequency: 1s
output.elasticsearch:
   <connection data>
```

## My question

**Can I use two levels of `*` in the directory hierarchy in the Filebeat configuration?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it works me on filebeat version 7.6.1 to monitor recursive

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/**/*
```

Answer (score 6):

Below is my filebeat version

```
$ filebeat.sh --version
filebeat version 5.6.2 (amd64), libbeat 5.6.2
```

And I tried below config

```
filebeat.prospectors:

- input_type: log

  paths:
    - /var/log/**/**/*


output.console:
  pretty: true

logging.level: debug
```

And it works great for me

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-10-07T18:12:17.694Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "vagrant",
    "name": "vagrant",
    "version": "5.6.2"
  },
  "input_type": "log",
  "message": "tarun",
  "offset": 6,
  "source": "/var/log/test1/test3/test.log",
  "type": "log"
}
```

Comment: Neat. Will give it a test drive ASAP.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot!